# Does the google-app-engine supports spring 4?

Tags: spring, google-app-engine, spring-mvc

I want to know which version of spring is now supported from Google app engine latest stable build. i.e. Spring 4 
what are its limitations ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have [this application](http://spring-mvc-enum.appspot.com) running on the AppEngine that uses Spring 4.x.

Comment: looks like we have Spring 4.x support .Can it supports resourse bundle concept .http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-resource-bundle-with-resourcebundlemessagesource-example/

Comment: Yes, you can read from file system and use resource. The limitation in gae is that an app cannot write data to the local file system.